# ServiceMix bundle status is "Active" even though bundle deployment fails

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I have (intentionally created situation to test my CI setup) a bundle which does not have all dependencies configured correctly. When I deploy that the deployment fails with an exception as it should:

```
2014-02-07 09:17:15,738 | ERROR | rint Extender: 3 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 103 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.10.7 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(ura) due "org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.envelope" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.envelope" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_11]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:143)[89:org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2:2.2.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:310)[89:org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2:2.2.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:412)[89:org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2:2.2.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:375)[89:org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2:2.2.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:279)[89:org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.soap.SoapJaxbDataFormat.createContext(SoapJaxbDataFormat.java:303)[206:org.apache.camel.camel-soap:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.doStart(JaxbDataFormat.java:254)[187:org.apache.camel.camel-jaxb:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.soap.SoapJaxbDataFormat.doStart(SoapJaxbDataFormat.java:101)[206:org.apache.camel.camel-soap:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
```

The problem is that the bundle status is still "Active". Why?

```
karaf@root> osgi:list 
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
   ID   State         Blueprint      Spring    Level  Name
[ 242] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   80] integraatiot-foo (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)
```

I would like to setup my CI builds to that they detect failed bundles using http://code.citytechinc.com/osgi-bundle-status-maven-plugin/. This idea fails since bundle status is always "Active".

Answer (score 1):

The bundle is active because it has been activated. This is normal. If an error occurred in some code *within* the bundle, that is nothing to do with the OSGi active state.

So you need to work out some way to report your internal failure such that it can be picked up by a CI build. I suggest using the OSGi LogService.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure all your dependencies are required and with the correct version. 
In this case it might be that the package your importing does existing in the wrong version. 
Or better did you make sure you only import the right version of the package with [2,3.0) for example. Especially the stack trace makes it suspicious to me that your using import without version range and therefore do import the JRE jaxb classes which usually do have version 0.0.0
To check which bundles are actually used for import log in the shell and do a bundle:header [bundleID]

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The problem is not that the deploy fails, that is intentional. The problem is that ServiceMix thinks and says that the bundle is "Active" although the deploy failed and the bundle is not running.

Comment: If the OSGi Framework says the Bundle is Active, all dependencies are resolved. Therefore your Import-Package is lacking a version range, therefore your bundle is failing on usage.